# Building AOSP master branch fails in Mac OSX

Tags: android, makefile, android-source

I am trying to build the master branch of AOSP, but it fails with following error:

```
host C++: validatekeymaps <= frameworks/base/tools/validatekeymaps/Main.cpp
In file included from frameworks/base/tools/validatekeymaps/Main.cpp:17:
In file included from frameworks/native/include/input/KeyCharacterMap.h:26:
In file included from frameworks/native/include/input/Input.h:25:
system/core/include/utils/Vector.h:20:10: fatal error: 'new' file not found
#include <new>
         ^
1 error generated.
make: *** [out/host/darwin-x86/obj/EXECUTABLES/validatekeymaps_intermediates/Main.o] Error 1
```

Does anyone has any idea on this? Where the "new" file should present? How would I solve this? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I believe is a clang error. clang does not need .h header extensions. I wouldn't bet my life on it but I will suggest updating your host clang to the newest or newer version. It is definitely a host problem. I've seen it before, but don't remember all, plus I'm on Ubuntu and don't build AOSP. I do see a recent change added `-Werror` now into system/core so try doing a Host `clang` update... even if you already have that file, an update may fix HOST include paths.

One more thought. Try: echo $(HOST_TOOLCHAIN_ROOT)
If you don't get a location you may have a clang which is too new... my reason/reference:

https://android.googlesource.com/platform/build/+/master/core/combo/HOST_darwin-x86_64.mk:

```
# gcc location for clang; to be updated when clang is updated
# HOST_TOOLCHAIN_ROOT is a Darwin-specific define
HOST_TOOLCHAIN_FOR_CLANG := $(HOST_TOOLCHAIN_ROOT)
```

Comment: I would definitely try this and let you know about the result. I am stuck on this since two weeks. Hope your answer would help me.